# What is the best way to run a custom app during an MDT UDI Task Sequence?

Tags: sccm-2012, mdt-2012

We have a very decentralized environment, and the UDI Wizard's OU selection page just isn't good enough to fit our needs, since I have to manually input every OU that a technician could choose when they build a machine.  I have developed a .NET app that will query Active Directory and inject the proper XML to populate that drop down box with every OU in our forest, but the width of the dropdown box is too small, and our long AD paths won't fit.

So, I have written my own OU tree chooser, and I would like that to run before the UDI wizard pops up.  This OU tree app allows a technician to select an OU to build the machine in, and then injects that OU into the UDI_Wizard_Config.xml file, so that the UDI wizard and the task sequence knows to put the machine in the chosen OU.  My questions are:
What is the best way to run this app? As a package? As a command line from a share?
How can I modify files in the MDT Toolkit during a TS?

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more complicated than this needs to be. Use the MDT database, that way it's all pre populated before the tech even runs the UDT enviroment. It'll take time now, but pay off in the long run.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean manually pre-populating the MDT database with all of our OUs?

Comment: You would either program the OUs in by role or location to make it easy, if you wanted TOTAL control, you would do it by the MAC or SERIAL, but yeah, using the MDT Database you can really drill down specifics of all kinds of stuff based on location or role.